# how to show the default page with language all?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I'm setting up a multi-language site in Joomla 2.5. Is it possible to show the default page with 'language all'?

open example.com/   ------  choose language en/zh    
if 'en'    
    go to example.com/en/    
else if 'zh'    
    go to example.com/zh/

my problem is ,when i open 'example.com/' it always jump to 'example.com/en/' or 'example.com/zh/' directly.

Answer (score 0):

When multi-language packs are installed, Joomla will redirect to the default one. If you would like more control over your languages and a language selector for the users, then I would recommend installing [JoomFish](http://www.joomfish.net/).

I haven't used JoomFish in a fairly long time but there might be a parameter to disable the language code on the end of the url upon entering the site, if not htaccess configuration might be needed.

Comment: hi,i'm a newbie of joomla. Dose JoomFish necessary?Joomla 2.5 has Language Filter which could 'Remove URL Language Code' & 'Menu associations'.If i choose 'yes' in 'Remove URL Language Code', it will remove the language tag on the end of the url.But ONLY the defalut language.'Main menu' with 'language-all' still won't show up.

Comment: like I said, it's been a quite a while since I used JoomFish for multi lingual sites. It would be a good idea for you to test it and see if it suits your needs.